# Date and Time in C# ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have field in my ASP.NET MVC4 View where the user should enter a datetime to be stored in the DB

now the user can enter a date and ignore the time so how can i force the user to enter both date and time and in case he ignore the time it will tell him error please enter time with date?

and one more thing
how can i make a test if:  startDate > endDate so it must return an error and ask the user to enter a date after the startDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery UI date picker is decent option . You can use it .

The other part of your question

```
var startdate = $('#datepickerStart').datepicker('getDate')
var enddate = $('#datepickerEnd').datepicker('getDate')

if(startdate >enddate )
return;
```

Comment: i used a datapicker but it still accepting the date alone !!!
i want the user to be obliged to put date and time not only date

Comment: One way is that you can append custom time field your self, by creating a drop down. but you will have little problem to append the date and time , and then compare them.

Or you can use this date picker which has time option too .

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Timepicker` which is based on `jQuery UI datepicker`(http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

or have

1.Text box for date using jquery ui date picker.

2.Text box /drop down list with values from 00 to 23 to select hours.

3.Text box/drop down list with values from 00 to 59 to select minutes.

4.Text box/drop down list with values from 00 to 59 to select seconds.

5.Make all as mandatory and check text box/ddl values before form submit.

6.In server side combine date and time to save in database.